# Out of Memory Error when Reading large file in Spark 2.1.0

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-xml

I want to use spark to read a large (51GB) XML file (on an external HDD) into a dataframe (using [spark-xml plugin](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)), do simple mapping / filtering, reordering it and then writing it back to disk, as a CSV file.

But I always get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` no matter how I tweak this.

**I want to understand why doesn't increasing the number of partitions stop the OOM error**

Shouldn't it split the task into more parts so that each individual part is smaller and doesn't cause memory problems?

> (Spark can't possibly be trying to stuff everything in memory and crashing if it doesn't fit, right??)

Things I've tried:

- repartitioning/coalescing to (5,000 and 10,000 partitions) the dataframe when reading and when writing (initial value is 1,604)
- using a smaller number of executors (6, 4, even with **2** executors I get OOM error!)
- decrease the size of split files (default looks like it's 33MB)
- give tons of RAM (all I have)
- increase `spark.memory.fraction` to 0.8 (default is 0.6)
- decrease `spark.memory.storageFraction` to 0.2 (default is 0.5)
- set `spark.default.parallelism` to a 30 and 40 (default is 8 for me)
- set `spark.files.maxPartitionBytes` to 64M (default is 128M)

All my code is here (notice i'm not caching anything):

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.read
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .schema(customSchema) // defined previously
  .option("rowTag", "row")
  .load(s"$pathToInputXML")

println(s"\n\nNUM PARTITIONS: ${df.rdd.getNumPartitions}\n\n")
// prints 1604

// i pass `numPartitions` as cli arguments
val df2 = df.coalesce(numPartitions)

// filter and select only the cols i'm interested in
val dsout = df2
  .where( df2.col("_TypeId") === "1" )
  .select(
    df("_Id").as("id"),
    df("_Title").as("title"),
    df("_Body").as("body"),
  ).as[Post]

// regexes to clean the text
val tagPat = "<[^>]+>".r
val angularBracketsPat = "><|>|<"
val whitespacePat = """\s+""".r


// more mapping
dsout
 .map{
  case Post(id,title,body,tags) =>

    val body1 = tagPat.replaceAllIn(body,"")
    val body2 = whitespacePat.replaceAllIn(body1," ")

    Post(id,title.toLowerCase,body2.toLowerCase, tags.split(angularBracketsPat).mkString(","))

}
.orderBy(rand(SEED)) // random sort
.write // write it back to disk
.option("quoteAll", true)
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.csv(output)
```

**NOTES**

- the input split are really small (33MB only), so why can't I have 8 threads each processing one split? it really shouldn't blow my memory (I've se

**UPDATE** I've written a **shorter version** of the code that just reads the file and then forEachPartition(println).

I get the same OOM error:

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.read
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .option("rowTag", "row")
  .load(s"$pathToInputXML")
  .repartition(numPartitions)

println(s"\n\nNUM PARTITIONS: ${df.rdd.getNumPartitions}\n\n")

df
  .where(df.col("_PostTypeId") === "1")
  .select(
   df("_Id").as("id"),
   df("_Title").as("title"),
   df("_Body").as("body"),
   df("_Tags").as("tags")
  ).as[Post]
  .map {
    case Post(id, title, body, tags) =>
      Post(id, title.toLowerCase, body.toLowerCase, tags.toLowerCase))
  }
  .foreachPartition { rdd =>
    if (rdd.nonEmpty) {
      println(s"HI! I'm an RDD and I have ${rdd.size} elements!")
    }
  }
```

P.S.: I'm using spark v 2.1.0. My machine has 8 cores and 16 GB ram.

Comment: Have you inspected the size of created partitions in Spark UI?

Comment: @Khozzy This is what I got when I ran the app with 1604 partitions for the read DF and 50 partitions for the DF to be written: [screenshot-spark-ui](http://i.imgur.com/a5LjEmc.png)

Comment: Yes, but look into the UI during job execution. You will find how long each task is executed and how your CPU is utilized (maybe there are stragglers).

Comment: I can't get a single task to complete, see the UI just before the OOM error: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/O3u6Rhu.png).. Also, I noted that there was a large spike in disk IO just before it crashes.

Comment: Actually, I do get some of the 8 initial tasks done, but when the 9th task starts, some of the tasks in the earlier group fail.

Comment: @Felipe Almeida I am facing a similar issue. Did you manage to solve this memory issue ?

Comment: did you find any soln to this problem?

Comment: @AmanTandon dont think so. I ended up doing something else. Can't remember, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running spark-shell and hence I increased the driver memory to a high number. Then I was able to load the XML.

```
spark-shell --driver-memory 6G
```

Source: https://github.com/lintool/warcbase/issues/246#issuecomment-249272263

Answer (score 0):

Because you are storing your RDD twice and
Your logic must be change like this or filter with SparkSql

```
 val df: DataFrame = SparkFactory.spark.read
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .schema(customSchema) // defined previously
      .option("rowTag", "row")
      .load(s"$pathToInputXML")
      .coalesce(numPartitions)

    println(s"\n\nNUM PARTITIONS: ${df.rdd.getNumPartitions}\n\n")
    // prints 1604


    // regexes to clean the text
    val tagPat = "<[^>]+>".r
    val angularBracketsPat = "><|>|<"
    val whitespacePat = """\s+""".r

    // filter and select only the cols i'm interested in
     df
      .where( df.col("_TypeId") === "1" )
      .select(
        df("_Id").as("id"),
        df("_Title").as("title"),
        df("_Body").as("body"),
      ).as[Post]
      .map{
        case Post(id,title,body,tags) =>

          val body1 = tagPat.replaceAllIn(body,"")
          val body2 = whitespacePat.replaceAllIn(body1," ")

          Post(id,title.toLowerCase,body2.toLowerCase, tags.split(angularBracketsPat).mkString(","))

      }
      .orderBy(rand(SEED)) // random sort
      .write // write it back to disk
      .option("quoteAll", true)
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .csv(output)
```

Comment: Making it all a single DF didn't really help.. I still have `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Answer (score -2):

You can change the heap size by adding the following in your environment variable:

1. Environment Variable name : _JAVA_OPTIONS
2. Environment Variable Value : -Xmx512M -Xms512M