# Getting NPE on simple Regex Replacing (Scala on Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nullpointerexception, emr

I wrote a simple code to parse a large XML file ( extract lines, clean text, and remove any html tags from it) using Apache Spark.

I'm seeing a NullPointerException when calling `.replaceAllIn` on a string, which is non-null.

The funny thing is that **I have no errors when I run the code locally**, using input from disk, but I get a `NullPointerException` when I run the same code on AWS EMR, loading the input file from S3.

Here is the relevant code:

```
val HTML_TAGS_PATTERN = """<[^>]+>""".r

// other code here...

spark
.sparkContext
.textFile(pathToInputFile, numPartitions)
.filter { str => str.startsWith("  <row ") }
.toDS()
.map { str =>

  Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"))

  val parts = str.split(""""""")

  var title: String = ""
  var body: String = ""

  // some code ommitted here

  title = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(title).toLowerCase.trim
  body = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(body).toLowerCase // decode xml entities


  println("before replacing, body is: "+body)

  // NEXT LINE TRIGGERS NPE
  body = HTML_TAGS_PATTERN.replaceAllIn(body, " ") // take out htmltags

}
```

Things I've tried:

- printing the string just before calling `replaceAllIn` to make sure it's not `null`.
- making sure the Locale is not null
- printing out the exception message, and stacktrace: it just tells me that that line is where the NullPointerException occurs. Nothing more

Things that are different between my local setup and AWS EMR:

- in my local setup, I load the input file from disk, on EMR I load it from s3.
- in my local setup, I run Spark in standalone mode, on EMR it's run in cluster mode.

---

Everything else is the same on my machine and on AWS EMR: Scala version, Spark version, Java version, Cluster configs...

I have been trying to figure this out for some hours and I can't think of anything else to try.

## EDIT

I've moved the call to `r()` to within the `map{}` body, like this:

```
val HTML_TAGS_PATTERN = """<[^>]+>"""

// code ommited

.map{

   body = HTML_TAGS_PATTERN.r.replaceAllIn(body, " ")    

 }
```

This also produces a **NPE**, wit the following stracktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1350)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at scala.util.matching.Regex.<init>(Regex.scala:191)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.r(StringLike.scala:255)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.r(StringLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:29)
    at ReadSOStanfordTokenize$$anonfun$2.apply(ReadSOStanfordTokenize.scala:102)
    at ReadSOStanfordTokenize$$anonfun$2.apply(ReadSOStanfordTokenize.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spar
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the regex inline ? Is it the regex that is null not the string body. It might be that the regex Isnt getting distributed correctly to the workers. Can you include some of the stack trace.

Comment: @Stephen I've tried just calling `.r()` inside the `map{}` and now this is what the stacktrace looks like: [gist link here](https://gist.github.com/queirozfcom/0aece2c4912017f0941a78a03de97fe9) (it does look like it's something to do with the regex)

Comment: @Stephen I now put the entire String declaration into the worker code and it looks like it's a win....=).... Write it out as an answer, so I can tick you green. =)

Comment: I think the solution is here is stop using regex for HTML / XML documents

Comment: @cricket_007 I did try using spark-xml to parse my file. But I kept running into OOM errors, even with 16GB of RAM given to Spark. Whereas reading the file as a text file and doing some minor parsing turned out to be very fast. I even asked a question on SO about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796443/out-of-memory-error-when-reading-large-file-in-spark-2-1-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try putting the regex inline like bellow.

This is a bit of a lame solution, you should be able to define a constant, maybe put it in a global `object` or something. Im not sure where you are defining it that would be a problem. But remember spark serialises the code and runs it on distributed workers, so something could be going wrong with that.

```
rdd.map { _ =>
   ...

   body = """<[^>]+>""".r.replaceAllIn(body, " ")    

 }
```

I get a very similar error when I run `.r` on a null String.

```
val x: String = null 
x.r 
java.lang.NullPointerException
  java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1350)
  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
  scala.util.matching.Regex.<init>(Regex.scala:223)
  scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r(StringLike.scala:281)
  scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r$(StringLike.scala:281)
  scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:29)
  scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r(StringLike.scala:270)
  scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r$(StringLike.scala:270)
  scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:29)
```

That error has slightly different line numbers, I think because of the scala version. Im on 2.12.2.

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea as to why a simple string can't be passed on to the map blocks? This seems pretty basic.

Comment: Its not because its a String or a regex. Its something to do with where that string lives. Eg, In a object or a anonymous class nested in something. Im not sure, maybe look into how spark serializes code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stephen's answer I found why I was getting a NPE on my UDF... I went this way (finding a match in my case):

```
def findMatch(word: String): String => Boolean = { s =>
    Option(s) match {
      case Some(validText) => if (word.toLowerCase.r.findAllIn(validText.toLowerCase).nonEmpty) true else false
      case None            => false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"<[^>]+>" was great, but I have one type of things in my HTML. it consists of a name of style and then parameters in between curly braces:

```
p { margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;line-height: 1.15; }
body { font-family: 'Arial';font-style: Normal;font-weight: normal;font-size: 14.6666666666667px; }.Normal { telerik-style-type: paragraph;telerik-style-name: Normal;border-collapse: collapse; }.TableNormal { telerik-style-type: table;telerik-style-name: TableNormal;border-collapse: collapse; }.s_4C87DD5E { telerik-style-type: local;font-family: 'Arial';font-size: 14.6666666666667px;color: #000000; }.s_8D20FCAB { telerik-style-type: local;font-family: 'Arial';font-size: 14.6666666666667px;color: #000000;text-decoration: underline; }.p_53E06EE5 { telerik-style-type: local;margin-left: 0px; }
```

I tried to extract them using the following, but it didn't work:

```
"\{[^\}]+\}"
```